# How to combine multiple documents of single collecton in to a single Document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, one-to-many

I have the multiple documents in the single Collection, I have followed [Model One-to-Many Relationships with Document References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/) pattern to store data. But i didn't got idea for aggregation to obtain expected result 
one of the sample is as follows ;-

```
 /* 1 */
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c47d98d91b1148f45895"), 
   "published" : "true", 
   "author" : "acacac",
    "postURL" : "main-post",
   "artId" : "123",
    "mainId" : "earth", 
   "date" : ISODate("2017-11-19T08:00:00.000Z")  
}

 /* 2 */
{   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c58e9f139f0880e3c78d"), 
    "body" : "main body part -1",
     "contentTitle" : "title-1",
    "contentCategory" : "category-1",
    "readingId" : "earth"
}
 /* 3 */
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c58e9f139f0880e3c78d"), 
    "body" : "main body part -2",
    "contentTitle" : "title-2",
    "contentCategory" : "category-2",
    "readingId" : "earth"
}
 /* 4 */
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c5c89f139f0880e3c78e"),
   "ans" : "ans 1",
   "question" : "this is the first q ?", 
   "quizId" : "earth" 
}
 /* 5 */
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c5c89f139f0880e3c78e"),
   "ans" : "ans 2",
   "question" : "this is the second q ?", 
   "quizId" : "earth"  
}
 ..
 ..

 etc
```

I tried with some of the aggregation method But i couldn't found solution i have following key-value as a common

```
 "mainId" : "earth",
 "readingId" : "earth"
 "quizId" : "earth"
```

How can i get  **output as following :-**

```
 {
   "_id" : ObjectId("5aa3c47d98d91b1148f45895"),
    "published" : "true", 
    "author" : "acacac",
    "postURL" : "main-post",
    "artId" : "123",
    "mainId" : "earth", 
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-19T08:00:00.000Z"),

   "content1" : [
            /* 2 */
         {  "body" : "main body part -1",
            "contentTitle" : "title-1",
            "contentCategory" : "category-1" },      
            /* 3 */
         {  "body" : "main body part -2",
            "contentTitle" : "title-2",
            "contentCategory" : "category-2" }                  
   ],
   "content2" : [
        /* 4 */
       {   "question" : "this is the first q ?",    
           "ans" : "ans 1" },

        /* 5 */
         {  "question" : "this is the second q ?", 
            "ans" : "ans 2"  }
   ]
}
..
..
. etc
```

Comment: Document Referenced Relationships Which is a guidelines for above problems [Parent Document vs Child Documents](https://www.quackit.com/mongodb/tutorial/mongodb_create_a_relationship.cfm)

Answer (score 1):

You can use $lookup. It is similar to SQL-outerjoin.

try with:

```
db.getCollection('tableName').aggregate([
{$match:{"mainId":{$exists:true}}}
,
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'tableName',
       localField: 'mainId',
       foreignField: 'readingId',
       as: "content1"
     }
}
,
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'tableName',
       localField: 'mainId',
       foreignField: 'quizId',
       as: "content2"
     }
}
])
```

where tableName is the name of your table.